# In the following scenario: why isn't the slot function being called?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, signals-slots, qt-signals

the following example has a working connection (i.e., it returns true), but the slot itself just isn't getting called/executed. I don't understand why this is the case:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "window.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Window win;

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
// window.h
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H
#include <QDebug>
#include "intermediary.h"

class Window : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    Window() {
        QObject::connect(&s, &Signal::a_signal,
        this, &Window::slotTest);
        Intermediary i;
    }
public slots:
    void slotTest() { qDebug() << "slot called"; }
private:
    Signal s;
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

```
// intermediary.h
#ifndef INTERMEDIARY_H
#define INTERMEDIARY_H
#include "Signal.h"

struct Intermediary {
    Intermediary() {
        Signal s;
        s.sendSignal();
    }
};

#endif // INTERMEDIARY_H
```

```
// signal.h
#ifndef SIGNAL_H
#define SIGNAL_H
#include <QObject>

class Signal : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT;
signals:
    void a_signal();
public:
    Signal() {}
    void sendSignal() {
        emit a_signal();
    }
};

#endif // SIGNAL_H
```

So my question is, how can you make changes to this code so that the connection will work as it should and call the slot, without having to change the structure completely (the structure of having an intermediary class that causes the signal to be emitted)? Thank you in advance.

I have tried pretty much all of the general tips, include Q_OBJECT, try new syntax,check the return value (returns true) etc. Maybe it has something to do with object lifetimes, but I don't know honestly. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You connect to one `Signal` then call `sendSignal` on a different one.

Comment: what is the use of `Intermediary` ? Why is the member of `WIndow` a `Signal` and not a `intermediary` ?

Comment: Yes, now I see that mistake. Thank you for pointing it out. I have an application where I have intermediary classes that cause signals, and that signal needs to be sent to a "base" class. I guess I'm wondering how I can send signals between different classes where the intermediary class shares the same instance object of the class with the signal. It might be bad design on my part.